# Django Request Returns JSON as 'str' instead of 'dict'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app that should receive a request from a payment API, instead of the API returning the JSON as 'dict' it returns a string, this makes it hard to use the response as a variable, below is the response and the code. Any help would be appreciated.

`request.body` returns

```
{
  "Body":{
    "stkCallback":{
      "MerchantRequestID":"31704-1162534-1",
      "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_170220211453010899",
      "ResultCode":0,
      "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata":{
        "Item":[
          {
            "Name":"Amount",
            "Value":1.00
          },
          {
            "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
            "Value":""
          },
          {
            "Name":"TransactionDate",
            "Value":20210217145321
          },
          {
            "Name":"PhoneNumber",
            "Value":
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The view

```
def callback(request):

    callback = json.dumps(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    body_data = json.loads(callback)

    print(body_data) # returns 'str' instead of 'dict'

    return render(request, 'callback.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json.dumps` is unnecessary. What you are doing is taking a string and converting it into json.
Suppose you have a string 'hello'. When you write `json.dumps('hello')` what happens? You get `'"hello"'` i.e. a string containing a string, and then you load it giving back a string to you. Try this instead:

```
def callback(request):
    body_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    # Rest of your code
```

Comment: If i don't use `json.dumps()` it does not pass the request that is why I have to use it. Is there another way of getting the values of the JSON?

Comment: @JosphatGitogo What do you mean it does not pass the request? does this `body_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))` not work?

Comment: It gives this error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @JosphatGitogo that means request.body does not have valid json. Try printing request.body `print(request.body.decode('utf-8'))` does it have valid json?

Comment: it returns this response.  {"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"107960-2768424-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_180220211712372482","ResultCode":0,"ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.","CallbackMetadata":{"Item":[{"Name":"Amount","Value":1.00},{"Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber","Value":""},{"Name":"Balance"},{"Name":"TransactionDate","Value":20210218171257},{"Name":"PhoneNumber","Value":}]}}}}

Comment: @JosphatGitogo Check at the end `"Value":` after this there's directly a `}`. That's not valid json. You need to send proper data from wherever you send it.

Comment: That is why I was trying json.dumps() first.